# carousel not fitting inside section in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am tring to make a carousel fill all the space in a section. But it is flowing out of the section. I need to position my carousel inside first section.
I am using twitter bootstrap3 and html5.

**CSS**

```
#section1 {
    height: 500px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1E88E5;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

img {
    height: 50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">


        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="1.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style=" height=20px ">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                        <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="2.jpg" alt="Chicago">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Chicago</h3>
                        <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="3.jpg" alt="New York">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>New York</h3>
                        <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/user1989/x3nnze01/5/)**

Comment: This question is about JavaScript/HTML/CSS, so you should consider using a [snippet](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Using a snippet makes it much easier for people to see what your problem is. A snippet makes it more likely that you get an accurate answer, and commonly results in people responding more positively to your question.

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you are dealing with responsiveness then your style will be as following:

```
#section1 {
min-height: 500px; //according to your background image size
color: #fff; 
background-color: #1E88E5; // no need if you are setting background image on whole div
background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
}


img {
    height: 50px;  // Don't hardcoded the height of image untill you deal with some specific div width.
}
```

In your case the `<div>` has class called `container-fluid`.
In your carousel `<div>` you have to add your `<img>` as follow:

```
 <div class="item active">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="1.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="display:inline-block;">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                 <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
            </div>
  </div>
```

And to clear this plz provide the snippet of your code to proper understanding.